# Place ScrollView between buttons

Tags: android, user-interface, scrollview

I have a problem with a design. Let me explain.[image]

I have a TextView in the top with some text lines. Then I have a layout with button, ScrollView, and button. I want to place ScrollWiew between the buttons. The problem is when I have a lot of Scrol items, everything is ok like in case 1. But when I have just a couple of items, they appear like in case 2. But I want them to be like in the case 3. I want the buttons and ScrollView to occupy the needed space in the bottom and the textView to take the remaining space. By the way I want these lines in the text view always to be shown, so the smallest space for text view is limited by these lines.

I want to do it using only XML.

My XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/myText1"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="28dip" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="12345"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="28dip" >
    </TextView>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0px"

    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_add"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:text="@string/add_text" />


    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:paddingRight="20dp"
                android:text="1"
                android:textColor="@color/black" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:paddingRight="20dp"
                android:text="2"
                android:textColor="@color/black" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
                android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:paddingRight="20dp"
                android:text="3"
                android:textColor="@color/black" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_cancel"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/cancel" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I tried to use RelativeLayout, but something went wrong, I guess. Because I got the same result.

Comment: Can you show us your XML file ? The reason why you have a blank with only 2 buttons may be caused by a problem with the "android:layout_height" of the scrollview.

Comment: add weight to the 2nd linear layout 'android:layout_weight="1"'

Comment: Yes, it really places my buttons and scroll to the bottom, but no that isn't what I want. I want to show as much scroll items as it can be placed on the screen in the given condition of showing all the text lines.

Comment: Can't u add scroll items now??

Comment: Sure, but they are not shown to the limit.

Answer (score 1):

Change your scrollview properties to

```
<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dip">
```

Comment: no, that isn't the answer. Again. I want the scrollview to be in the bottom. With such properties it stays in the top even if I have no items in the scrollView